# Assertion is not within its valid time range. Ensure that the access token is not expired before using it for user assertion, or request a new token

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, access-token, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to generate access token using `On-Behalf-Of flow` which will be used to authenticate API calls. I am adding a claim called userIdToken which is value of id_token in startup file(sample below). Then retrieving the value from `ClaimsPrincipal` to to generate token using `AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf` method.

It works perfectly fine until userIdToken expires(1 hour). But it won't refresh the userIdToken and hence it throws exception when `AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf` method is called. Doing a fresh login works for next one hour since it uses new userIdToken .

How can I add token refresh functionality to the existing approach?

**Error:**
`Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalUiRequiredException: 'AADSTS500133:  Assertion is not within its valid time range. Ensure that the access token is not expired before using it for user assertion, or request a new token. Current time: 2022-06-16T10:33:17.8173399Z, expiry time of assertion 2022-06-16T06:49:33.0000000Z.`

##### Startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication("SomeCustomType")
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
                {
                    Configuration.Bind("AzureAD", options);
                    options.SaveTokens = true;

                    options.Events.OnTicketReceived = async context =>
                    {
                        var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal.Identity;
                        claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("DirectAadAuth", "true"));
                        
                        try
                        {
                            claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("userIdToken", context.Properties.GetTokens().First().Value));
                            var authedUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claimsIdentity.Claims, "SomeCustomType"));

                            await context.HttpContext.SignInAsync("CustomType", authedUser, new AuthenticationProperties{IsPersistent = true});
                        }
                        catch (System.Exception)
                        {
                          
                        }
                    };
                }
                )
                .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(Configuration.GetSection("CustomConfig").Get<CustomConfigModel>().DownstreamApiScopes)
                .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

##### TokenClient.cs

```
public async Task<string> GetAccessTokenAsync(ClaimsPrincipal user)
    {
        var userIdToken = user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "userIdToken")?.Value;
        var userAssertion = new UserAssertion(userIdToken);
        var scopedResult = await clientApplication.AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf(scopes, userAssertion).ExecuteAsync();
        
        return scopedResult.AccessToken;
        
    }
```

Comment: Hi @kaigalmane I am facing a similar issue, can you guide as to how to fixed this issue please?